# Output random hex from an executable

Tags: java, c++, c, perl, hex

I am currently looking at how to output an executable as hex, although instead of outputting it all as hex, I would just like a random selection of hex's output for example 16 hex's.

E.g.

hex.exe > input.exe < randomhex.txt

Comment: ?!???!? it's not really clear what you are after - edit your question to clarify, else it will get closed.

Comment: [Data::HexDump::Range](http://p3rl.org/Data::HexDump::Range#Vertical_orientation)